# Display time interval in minutes using joda Date time to display in Calendar

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime-format, android-calendar, android-jodatime

> I want to display list of time interval with **15 minutes or 30 minutes** like

like

```
1:00
1:15
1:30
1:45
```

or

```
1:00
1:30
2:00
2:30
```

below code is using **Joda Date time library** and it's showing time with interval of hours . I simply want to display time with interval of 15 or 30 minutes .

```
val hourDateTime = DateTime().withDate(2000, 1, 1).withTime(0, 0, 0, 0)
        for (i in 1..23) {
                val formattedHours = Formatter.getHoursWithMinutes(context!!, hourDateTime.withHourOfDay(i))
        }
```

**Formatter.kt**

```
    fun getHoursWithMinutes(context: Context, dateTime: DateTime) = dateTime.toString("h:mm a")
```

Instead of showing **date(s)** like **1:00 ,2:00 ,3:00 ,4:00** display with interval of 15 or 30 minutes

[Currently working View](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar/master/fastlane/metadata/android/en-US/images/phoneScreenshots/app_3.jpg) which is working using [Simple Calendar](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar)

I have tried another approach written below but this time time interval changes but hours remain same like

**12:00 -> 12:30 -> 12:00 -> 12:30**

```
   val hourDateTime = DateTime().withDate(2000, 1, 1).withTime(0, 0, 0, 0)
    var interval = 30
    for (i in 1..23) {
        if(i == 1 ) interval = 0
        val formattedHours = Formatter.getHoursWithMinutes(context!!, hourDateTime.withMinuteOfHour(interval) )
        interval += 30
        if(interval == 60) interval = 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

I can’t write Kotlin. Please translate from my Java.

```
    Duration interval = Duration.ofMinutes(15);

    LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(1, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(time);
        time = time.plus(interval);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> 01:00
> 01:15
> 01:30
> 01:45
> 02:00
> 02:15
> 02:30
> 02:45
> 03:00
> 03:15
> ```

Set the interval to `Duration.ofMinutes(30)` to get 01:00, 01:30, etc.

I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, through the backport, see below. java.time is the successor of Joda-Time. I am sure something very similar to the above is possible with Joda-Time too in case you are already using Joda-Time and don’t want to migrate to java.time just now.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.